# collections relationship in Mongodb (node.js)

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection called `UserInfo` contains:

`userName`: "john doe"
`userID`: "100"

I also a have collection called `Friends` contains:

`userID`: "100"
`friendID`: "200"

Each user can have multiple friends.  So I attempt to add another:

`userID`: "100"
`friendID`: "300"

and so on.

Is this the right way to do this?  I need the ability to add and remove friends from a user.

Another approach I can think of for `UserInfo`:

`userName`: "john doe"
`userID`: "100"
`friends`: "200, 300, 400"    //etc.

Or other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a whole section in the mongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) talking about the pros and cons of embedding documents vs referencing them in a separate collection.
It really depends on the scenario and requirements (in short: embedded documents allow for atomic operations and in general some performance gains but may cause duplication).

In your specific case I would most probably go with an embedded array of friend IDs (your last shown option) and not use a separate `Friends` collection as storing the friend's IDs causing no data duplication anyway.